# ER Modeling - diagramming a Many-to-Many relationship between two attributes

Tags: database, entity-relationship, data-modeling, erd

There exists an entity X with two attributes, A and B. The ER model so far has one table:

```
[_X_| A | B ]
```

Now the model has to be updated to show a many-to-many relationship between A and B. The relationship is optional both ways - there is no dependency between A and B.

Does the existing diagram *already imply* a many-to-many relationship between attributes A and B? Or, because we are now explicitly stating there must be a relationship between A and B, we must also create new tables and draw relationship arcs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation `X -> A,B` does imply *a* many-to-many relation between A and B (`A ->> X -> B` and `B ->> X -> A`) in which `X` acts like a surrogate identifier.  If you can generate new `X`s freely, then the table could physically be used as such (though you'd likely be changing or conflating the table predicate(s)), but without a unique constraint on `A,B` you're open to integrity problems.  It would probably be best to create a new relation/table.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I forgot that if you wanted to add an entry to the A-B relationship, you'd need an X to go with it.